# select menu default values not rendering in symfony

Tags: forms, symfony1, widget

I am using Symfony 1.4, and am using embedded forms to place multiple similar forms into one form for a configuration page. I am having success showing the form, but the default values of the sfWidgetFormChoice widgets are not being rendered, i.e. the selected="selected" attribute is gone from the HTML.

Incidentally, the default values show up if I don't use embedded forms. The problem with avoiding embedded forms is that each form has identical inputs and therefore overwrites itself.

The action code is as such, some code omitted for brevity:

```
  $serviceFormArray = array();
  $this->fullForm = new ConfigForm();

  foreach($this->serviceArray as $net => $service)
  {

    $this->partialForm = new ConfigForm();

    foreach($service as $typeId => $val)
    {
      $typeObj = Doctrine::getTable('Type')->find($typeId); 
      $typeField = new sfWidgetFormChoice(array(
          'default' => $val,
          'choices' => array('1' => 'on', '0' => 'off'),
          'label' => $typeObj->name)
          );

      $typeField->setDefault($val);

      $serviceFormArray[$typeObj->name] = $typeField;
    }
    $netObj = Doctrine::getTable('Network')->find($net);
    $this->partialForm->setWidgets($serviceFormArray);
    $this->fullForm->embedForm($netObj->name,$this->partialForm);

  }
```

and the template looks like this, some code omitted for brevity:

```
<div class="sectionBox">
  <?php echo $fullForm->renderFormTag('/configure/submitconfig') ?>
    <?php foreach ($fullForm->getVisibleFields() as $part => $field): ?>
    <div class="settingsField">
      <?php echo $field->renderLabel() ?>
      <?php echo $field->render() ?>
      <input type="hidden" name="plug" value="<?php echo $plugName; ?>"/>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <div id="submitConfig"><input type="submit" value="Save"/></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting default value via `$form->setDefault($name, $default)`.

```
$this->partialForm->setDefault($typeObj->name, $val);
```